# Data cannot be updated when slide pages in Android Mobile App

Tags: java, android

As title described, the data cannot be updated when slide between two neighbor pages, but data can be updated when I jump over to the 3rd page. For example, in the 1st page, I update the number 1 to 11, the data in page 1 will still be 1 after I slide to the neighboring page and slide back to page 1; but the number in page 1 will update to 11 after I directly go to 3rd page and go back to page 1. Any one knows how to figure it out? Thanks!

For function 1 to function 4, it's a class extends Fragment

public class function# extends Fragment

Here is my code :

```
public static class AppSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter

            {
                public AppSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
                    {
                        super(fm);
                    }

                public Fragment getItem(int i)
                    {
                        switch (i)
                            {
                                case 0:
                                    return new function1();

                                case 1:
                                    return new function2();

                                case 2:
                                    return new function3();

                                case 3:
                                    return new function4();
                            }

                        return null;
                    }

                public int getCount()
                    {
                        return 4;
                    }

                public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
                    {
                        switch (position)
                            {
                                case 0:
                                    return "Quotes";

                                case 1:
                                    return "Trading";

                                case 2:
                                    return "Portfolio";

                                case 3:
                                    return "Orders";
                            }

                        return "";
                    }
            }
```

Comment: What is function1/2/3/4 etc? We can't help you with this code. Where is the value which is updated?

Comment: Thanks for correction, Marco. I just edit it. See changes

Answer (score 0):

Call `ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);`

On your ViewPager .. Or is the value you want Zero.. Mhm I forget.